# Algo de errado nas referencias usando duas camadas no Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Fiz um exemplo em `Entity 5.0`  e com 1 camada funcionou perfeito.

Agora separei em `UI` e `DA`L, mas esta dando erro. A mesma página que funcionou na camada `DAL` quando feita na `UI` esta dando erro.
Acredito que seja alguma falta de referência.

O erro é:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.

Source Error: 

Line 41:    using (var ctx = new DAL.TracesEntities())
Line 42:    {
Line 43:        var lambda = ctx.Traces.Where(q => q.DataBaseName == "megacorretor" || q.DataBaseName == "stats_mega")
Line 44:                               .GroupBy(a => new { a.TextData, a.DataBaseName })
Line 45:                               .Select(b => new { ...
```

Fiz referencia ao projeto DAL e a DLL:

```
packages\EntityFramework.5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll
```

Não lembro se devo copiar algum `.tt` algo para a `UI` para funcionar. Estranho que o interlisense na `UI` funciona perfeitamente com o `entity` da `DAL`

Comment: você chegou a mudar o namespace das classes movidas? Se não mudou, é por isso que o Intellisense ainda reconhece

Comment: Não sei a resposta, mas para evitar esse tipo de erro você poderia usar code first. Existe uma ferramenta bem simples que gera as classes pra você e deixa o código mais limpo do que com edmx, é o entity power tools.
Tem um exemplo dele no meu blog http://devrodrigosantos.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/comecando/

Comment: Sim mudei o namespace, alias criei um arquivo novo na UI porém com o mesmo código..intelisense 100% funciona porém ele não acha o recurso!
Creio que aqui todos desenvolvam com várias camadas pra ninguém da esse erro?

Comment: Não tinha como fazer Code first o banco de dados já existe com 20GB de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro significa que o `resource` (refere-se ao EDMX) não foi achado. É nesse arquivo EDMX que ficam guardados os metadados usados para mapear o seu modelo de classes para o modelo do banco de dados.

Verifique se no designer do seu arquivo EDMX, a **propriedade `MetadataArtifactProcessing` está definida para `Embed in Output Assembly`**... é isso que faz o EDMX se transformar em um `resource`.

Comment: Já estava em 'Embed in Output Assembly' também mudei o Build Action para 'Embedded Resource' e Copy to output em Always e tb não funcionou..continua o erro.

Comment: Passei por esse problema e o diretorio do meu edmx estava com o metada incorreto. Obrigado Pela resposta @Miguel Angelo.